# getting error while firebase version 9 FCM implementation in Next 12

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, firebase-cloud-messaging

I wanted to add push notification on my next js(version 12) app. so implemented firebase Cloud messaging on that. implementation looks like this :

```
import { initializeApp, getApp, getApps } from "firebase/app"
import { getMessaging, getToken } from "firebase/messaging"
import { firebaseConfig } from "./config"

const app = !getApps.length ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : getApp()
```

and added this **cloudMessaging** function for getting FCM token. and **onMessageListener** function for displaying foreground messages

```
export const cloudMessaging = async () => {
  const token = await isTokenAvailable()
  if (token !== null) {
    return Promise.resolve({
      status: true,
      token: token,
    })
  }
  try {
    const permission = await Notification.requestPermission()

    const messaging = getMessaging(app)
    console.log(messaging)
    console.log(permission)
    if (permission === "granted") {
      const FCM_TOKEN = await getToken(messaging, {
        vapidKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FCM_VAPID_KEY,
      })
      if (FCM_TOKEN) {
        localStorage.setItem("fcm_token_prac", FCM_TOKEN)
        return Promise.resolve({
          status: true,
          token: FCM_TOKEN,
        })
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err, "cloudmessaging error")
    return Promise.resolve({
      status: false,
    })
  }
}
export const onMessageListener = () => {
  const messaging = getMessaging(app)
  console.log(messaging)

  return new Promise((res) => {
    messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
      res(payload)
    })
  })
}
```

And invoking these function from my Layout component

```
useEffect(() => {
    firebaseInit()
    async function firebaseInit() {
      try {
        await cloudMessaging()
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    }
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    onMessageListener()
      .then((payload) => {
        console.log(payload, "onMessageListener")
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err, "onMessageListener useEffect"))
  }, [])
```

But getting this error in my console :

```
 TypeError: messaging.onMessage is not a function
    at eval (firbase.js?100f:58:15)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at onMessageListener (firbase.js?100f:57:10)
    at eval (Layout.js?4f8d:33:22)
    at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js?ac89:23049:1)
```

I'm unable to find out where I made the mistake. Can anyone guide me to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try adding `onMessage` in the import part.

```
import { getMessaging, getToken, onMessage } from "firebase/messaging"
```

Remove `messaging` on line

```
messaging.onMessage
```

becomes

```
onMessage((payload) => {
    res(payload)
})
```

This is for SDK version 9